# Mathematical analysis book with Lambda calculus notation.

Tags: real-analysis, logic, book-recommendation, lambda-calculus

I am searching for a book in which we can find the theorems and definition written using $\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta $  types of notation only. when I am wringing proves it is very easy to follow them when I write down the problem in  $\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta $ form.

The notation I am talking about is used in lambda calculus. I am not very familiar with Lambda calculus. The logic is very clear when I read things written explicitly in the form of Lambda calculus notation.

I am a 3-year undergraduate. suggest some Mathematical analysis book.

Comment: I have never seen $\forall \epsilon$ and $\exists \delta$ used in $\lambda$-calculus. There terms look like for example $\lambda x\ y . y \ x$. Can you give some examples of theorems and definitions written the way you want?

Comment: This is a switch. I see people use "proof" when they mean "prove" all the time, but I don't recall seeing someone use "prove" when they meant "proof" before. But that is just me whining about a pet peeve. Your real problem is that md2perpe is right, "$\forall, \exists$" are not "Lamda calculus". If you get an answer to the question you asked, you will almost certainly be deeply disappointed.

Comment: I do not think that you will find it...

Comment: I agree with @Mauro ALLEGRANZA that there is probably no such book. However, if this notation is important for you to become familiar with for some reason, then it seems to me that it would be good practice to rewrite the theorems yourself. And if you think this is something others would be interested in, then perhaps make a .pdf file or something and post it somewhere.